# PWM circuit explanation

Tags: pwm, opto-isolator

I have the following circuit that I am using to implement an Arduino project. Now I tend to focus more on the coding side of things usually so I lack the electrical knowledge. Could someone please provide me an explanation of the workings of this circuit.

I am trying to understand how each of these components are used and fit together, and how their required values were found. 
Much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: looks like a dodgy attempt at building a solid-state relay. it's going to pass about 3.5mA even in the off state so it will probably cause LED or CFL lamps blink when they should be dark. and as Trevor says when you turn it on after a second or so it will start to cook itself.  you're better off buying a solid-state relay.

Comment: *lack the electrical knowledge* + mains connected: that means you should follow Jasen's advise: buy a ready-made solution for this, a solid state relay or a mains switch module, you can find both on eBay.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit acts as a self powered AC switch. The circuit must have the lamp attached to function.

The IRF830 is acting as the switch here and is either on or off. As you can see, although a MOSFET if not designed for AC, since it is connected through that diamond shaped bridge rectifier, the load current always flows one way through the MOSFET. The MOSFET will normally be turned off by the pull down resistor R2.

D6, and R5 tap off some DC current to create a high voltage raw power supply. This high voltage level is then reduced through R4, R2 and D1 to produce a 10V supply that is maintained on C1.

When the Arduino lights the LED the phototransistor uses that 10V to charge the gate of the MOSFET turning it on.

NOTE: When the MOSFET is on, there will no longer be any voltage available to keep C2 and C1 charged. As such I suspect this circuit is controlled by some form of PWM, hopefully with the aid of some form of zero crossing detector, so that the MOSFET is turned off long enough to maintain the 10V on capacitor C1. If not, the lamp will turn out when C1 discharges or worse (See warning 2).

Also note that the return current for all this is the lamp. When off the current will be small, not enough to heat the lamp filament, but the lamp socket is still very much live.

As for the values, the 10V zener maintains sufficient voltage to ensure the MOSFET turns on adequately, R3 and R4 limit how much current is fed to that zener so it does not burn out. The values for the caps R2 will be what the designer deemed adequate for whatever AC frequency this was designed for. **C2 is actually undersized** in that schematic. If should be at least a 350V part.

**WARNING 1:** First and foremost, the circuit is lethal to work on. If you plan on building this use extreme caution.

**WARNING 2:** Second, as I mentioned the thing loses power if you keep the LED lit too long. As such the gate voltage will fall and the MOSFET will enter the linear region till enough voltage is across it to keep the gate alive. It will then get VERY hot and may destroy itself or even catch fire. This is a design flaw with this circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the in dept explanation. Yes it does make use of PWM in the code to control the intensity of the lamp

Comment: @mekzek make sure your code never stops in debug mode or crash mode with the LED driven.